# Filtering two arrays of strings with lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have two arrays of strings like:

```
var array = ["one", "two", "three", "six", "twelve", "thirteen", "twenty", "forty", "fifty"]

var array1 = ["on", "t"];
```

I want to filter array to take out any elements that starts with any of the elements in array1.  So after filtering array should look like:

```
["six", "forty", "fifty"];
```

I also need to filter array by taking out any elements that have within them any of the elements in array1.  So after filtering array should look like:

```
["six"];
```

Right now I'm using something like:

```
_.filter(array, function(n){return _.map(array1, function(m){
                    return _.startsWith(n, m)})})
```

which is returning

```
[[true, false], [false, true], [false, true], [false, false], 
[false, true], [false, true], [false, true], [false, false], [false, false]];
```

Comment: OK, so whats your question?

Comment: I want to filter array by array1, preferably with lodash.  I don't mean to be obtuse but what's not clear from the post?

Comment: You still haven't asked a question. So far you've just made statements. You've been part of SO long enough to know that we operate by giving *answers* to *questions*.

Comment: How do you filter array by array1?

Comment: Please show your code and we'll look to see what's wrong with it. This is not a "write me some code to do this" service.

Comment: At this point, I'm wondering why you want to bust my balls instead being a little more helpful; you could've said that at the beginning.

Comment: Here we always need two things: (1) code, and (2) a question.

Comment: Suffice to say, the attitude at SO has changed in the last year. If it were like this I'd never have been able to start learning how to code. As it stands I'm still relatively early in learning to code but a lot of time a true novice, especially if self taught may not even no how to phrase a question and the point of coming to SO is, in many cases for true self-taught beginners and they need help with the last mile to even get started.  I appreciate your high level of skill to the point that you can no longer relate to the more mortal ones of us.

Comment: Anyhow, do you want to haze me or would you like to be helpful?

Comment: Take it easy, bro. So, what output are you getting?

Comment: @Jonathan, I posted what I'm getting back which is giving me some indication but I still can't figure out where to go from there.

Comment: Why do you have a map? Filter method should just return true/false.

Comment: @FrEaKmAn, I'm trying to go through two arrays so I want to filter one by all of the values of the other.  What should I do?

Comment: You don't want a map operation then. You want to filter on array, and for each entry you can do a reduce operation to check if any of the items in array1 match, in which case, the filter should resolve as you intend it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No lodash needed.

```
var array1 = ["one", "two", "three", "six", "twelve", "thirteen", "twenty", "forty", "fifty"]

var array2 = ["on", "t"];

array1=array1.filter(function(a){
  return array2.every(function(b){
    return !a.includes(b)
  })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pbvLn788/

filter(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

every(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

includes(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: Great answer with pure JS.

Comment: Glad to help. And, BTW, no one was hazing you earlier. You just need to provide the question and code needed to get the answers you want. You're asking someone to give you something for free, so make it as easy as possible for us to help you, and don't be rude when we ask for needed info. No one owes you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer right before I saw Jonathan M.  Thanks for the post you beat me to it.  Here's how I did it with LoDash.

```
_.filter(array, function(n){if (_.contains(_.map(array1, function(m){
                              return _.startsWith(n, m)}), true)){
                            } else {
                              return n;}}));
```

Comment: You don't need the `startsWith()` since you're using `contains()`. If it starts with a character, it also contains the character.

Answer (score 0):

Lo-dash way of solving this problem:

```
var array1 = ["one", "two", "three", "six", "twelve", "thirteen", "twenty", "forty", "fifty"]

var array2 = ["on", "t"];

var myArray = array1;

_.remove(myArray, function(arr1Elem) {
  return _.some(array2, function(arr2Elem) {
    return _.includes(arr1Elem, arr2Elem);
  });
});

console.log(myArray);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a2exvq3r/